# Python pass variable from class in one file to another file

Tags: class, variables, python-3.5

i have following code in two files:

operation1.py

```
class App_Name():
    def __init__(self):
        self.type_option = ""

    def Intro(self):
        self.type_option = input("Chose one option: ")
...

start = App_Name()
start.Intro()
```

menu.py

```
from operation1 import App_name

aP = App_Name()

if aP.type_option == 1:
    do smth
elif aP.type.type_option == 2:
   do smth 2
```

If i type 1, i expect to run commands from first `if` condition. When i try to print `App_name.type_option` it seems to be empty. How can i pass value of `aP.type_option` to menu.py?

Comment: `option` has only 1 'p'. you're defining 2 distinct variables...

Comment: i typed code here by hand, didn't copy it - it is typo

Comment: problem: `if aP.type_option == 1:` cannot happen: `type_option` is a string in python 3.

Comment: problem #2: you created 2 separate instances. You have to do `ap.Intro()` in `menu.py`

Answer (score 0):

`start` and `aP` are 2 different instances. Since `type_option` is bound to one instance, `start.type_option` contains the input (as string), whereas `aP.type_option` contains the empty string you set in the `__init__` method.

Remove `start` instanciation in your `operation1` module or you'll be prompted when importing it!

Then fix `menu.py` as follows:

```
from operation1 import App_name

aP = App_Name()
aP.Intro()

if aP.type_option == "1":
    do smth
elif aP.type.type_option == "2":
   do smth 2
```

(note that comparison must be done against strings because Python 3 `input` returns strings, doesn't evaluate literals like python 2 `input` did)

Comment: how can i call for value of `type_option` from operation1.py to menu.py, assuming i have to keep `start.Intro()` in operation1.py?

Comment: try `operation1.start.type_option`, and you don't need an instance in `menu.py` in that case.